# Формирование столбца Pandas на основе данных из двух таблиц при выполнении условий

Tags: python, pandas

Граждане, всю голову сломал. Знаний не хватает немного. Натолкните на мысль.

Дано:

1. Таблица Output.xlsx откуда берется основа. Убираю не нужное, именую столбцы.
2. Файл BD.csv, где находится дополнительная информация, на основе которой необходимо сделать дополнительные колонки в Таблице Output.xlsx

Задача:

Опираясь на картинку ниже пошагово

1. Необходимо проверить у первого поставщика все заполненные поля с артикулами. Пустые поля пропускаются. И если у поле заполнено и стоит артикул, то необходимо проверить наличие товара в CSV файле.
2. В CSV Файле сортируем, что бы выводились данные только нужного поставщика, т.к. артикулы разных поставщиков бывают одинаковыми.
3. По артикулу (в нашем примере D001263) находим нужную нам строчку.
4. Если товара нет в наличии, то возвращаемся на шаг 1 и проверяем следующий артикул. Если товар в наличии (len>0 или значение !=0), то:
5. Из столбца 'ОПТ' берем оптовую стоимость и вставляем ее на место шага 6
6. Когда столбец "Цена Attrade" будет заполнена, то переходим к следующему поставщику.

В итоге должно получиться 15 новых столбцов справа, т.е. столько же, сколько и самих поставщиков. И обязательно цена в новом столбце ставится только в том случае, если товар в наличии(Проверяем на 4 шаге).

```
import pandas as pd
import openpyxl
import numpy as np
import openpyxl  
df = pd.read_excel('Output.xlsx', header=None).loc[1:, :]
df = df[[0, 10, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31]]
df.rename(columns = {0:'Номер в Avito - Id', 10:'Название объявления - Title', 14:'Склад', 15:'Цена склада', 16:'Attrade', 17:'Slami', 18:'Invask', 19:'Proaudio', 20:'Arispro', 21:'Artimusic', 22:'Pop music', 23:'Roland', 24:'Okno-Audio', 25:'Grand', 26:'Lutner', 27:'LTM', 28:'Neva-sound', 29:'DJ Store', 30:'United Music', 31:'Итоговая цена'}, inplace = True)
fr = pd.read_csv('BD.csv') 
with pd.ExcelWriter('Output.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a", if_sheet_exists='replace') as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Processing", index=False)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы много времени потратили на отрисовку алгоритма в картинках, а хотя бы часть исходных данных для примера приложить не подумали.

Предположим, у вас есть датафрейм goods (gname - название товара, art - артикул):

```
  gname  art
0   aaa  111
1   bbb  222
2   ccc  333
```

и датафрейм поставщиков suppliers (sname - имя поставщика, art - артикул, left - остаток):

```
  sname  art  left
0  sup1  111     3
1  sup2  111     2
2  sup3  111     3
3  sup1  222     1
4  sup3  222     4
5  sup2  333     5
6  sup3  333     6
```

дальше делаем просто merge, фактически получая пересечение двух таблиц:

```
merged = pd.merge(goods, suppliers, how ='inner', on =['art'])
```

merge:

```
  gname  art sname  left
0   aaa  111  sup1     3
1   aaa  111  sup2     2
2   aaa  111  sup3     3
3   bbb  222  sup1     1
4   bbb  222  sup3     4
5   ccc  333  sup2     5
6   ccc  333  sup3     6
```

теперь приводим к нужному виду:

```
res = merged.pivot(index=["gname", "art"], columns="sname", values="left")
```

получаем res:

```
sname      sup1  sup2  sup3
gname art                  
aaa   111   3.0   2.0   3.0
bbb   222   1.0   NaN   4.0
ccc   333   NaN   5.0   6.0
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Я рассчитывал получить ответ: "pd.merge тебе в помощь" - этого было бы достаточно для зацепки. А тут еще и с примером, спасибо! Это мой второй вопрос, поэтому не подумал пример выложить. Исправлюсь.